# Opencart installation problem

Tags: php, mysql, opencart

I am trying to install [opencart](http://www.opencart.com/) for the first time in my local machine. I am using xampp 1.7.4 PHP 5.3.4 and Windows7 is my OS. I try to follow all the steps describe [HERE](http://www.opencart.com/index.php?route=documentation/documentation&path=4). But, after giving the db name, db user name and password when I press "Continue" button I am getting the following error message:

> Variable 'sql_mode' can't be set to
>   the value of 'NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO'

I try to google it with this error message but do not find anything. Please help me.....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove below line from opencart.sql

```
SET SQL_MODE="NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO"
```

you can find opencart.sql  file in install folder

Above error comes if different version of mysql is being used.

Answer (score 19):

Change the lines of code from the following files:

- install/cli_install.php

  Search for `$db->query("SET @@session.sql_mode = 'MYSQL40'");` and replace with `$db->query("SET @@session.sql_mode = ''");`
- install/model/install/install.php

  Search for `$db->query("SET @@session.sql_mode = 'MYSQL40'");` and replace with
  `$db->query("SET @@session.sql_mode = ''");`

Comment: Your comment is not very clear, @Yogesh, and this question was asked 7 years ago. Which might suggest that at the moment your solution was not available (or that it wouldn't work then).

Answer (score 8):

Opencart installation Fix

navigate to your install.php file in the following directory
**/install/model/install.php**
edit the file and delete exactly this text:

```
$db->query("SET @@session.sql_mode = 'MYSQL40'");
```

Answer (score 4):

The issue is that "sql_code=MYSQL40" has been deprecated on MySQL since 5.7.22 (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_mysql40)

My solution is similar to @Yogesh Sanger.  Instead of setting the sql_code value to an empty string, I just remove the line `$db->query("SET @@session.sql_mode = 'MYSQL40'");`

For those using Unix, here is a command to remove the culprit

```
sed -i '/MYSQL40/d' <OpenCart Directory>/install/cli_install.php
sed -i '/MYSQL40/d' <OpenCart Directory>/install/model/install/install.php
```

Answer (score 0):

Becouse at this time are 5 results on google regarding to this.... and i didn't found **SET SQL_MODE="NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO**

I had similar problem. My problem was Error 1231,unable to SET SQL_MODE=MYSQL40 . Something like that.

I solved in this way:

1. go to system/database/mysql.php find line 50 or

   `trigger_error('Error: ' . mysql_error($this->link) . '<br />Error No: ' . mysql_errno($this->link) . '<br />' . $sql);`
   `exit();`
2. comment the `//exit();`
3. drop all your tables from database.
4. refresh to resend

In this way the code will continue and the cart will be able to finish the configuration.

I hope it helped someone.

PS: I posted this on my website: [w3bdeveloper.com](http://w3bdeveloper.com/how-to/opencart-install-problem-set-sql_mode-mysql40/)